# Series connected capacitor and resistor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors

I want to ask something that I see in the circuit. As follows,
[image]

What is the purpose of using 2R resistor in this circuit?

Comment: Replaced comment with answer below.

Comment: Add whole circuit to your question, please. Not just a small section.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are asking what is purpose of resistor in this RC circuit? Or are you asking what is the meaning of "2R" value?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple RC circuit. The resistor slows down charging of the capacitor.

Comment: But 2R is too small, is not it?

Comment: @OnurBayrak That is another question! You have asked what is purpose of that resistor, haven't you?

Comment: Yes, I said that

Comment: @OnurBayrak Then my answer is exactly about that.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the marking of 2R for that resistor would tell you that the value of that resistor should be 2 times the value of a similar (or referenced) resistor marked only as R somewhere else in the circuit.

Comment: OK, two ways of looking at this.  Did you want to know what is the purpose of the using the designation "2R" ?  Or were you asking what is the function of the resistor marked as 2R?

Comment: What is the function of the resistor marked as 2R?

Comment: OK, so the answer from Chupacabras is more fitting.  But from your other comment don't assume 2R means 2 Ohms.

Comment: I have never seen that as a convention, typically in the circuits I have seen, 2R would be a 2 ohm resistor, similar 2K would be 2000 ohms and 2M would be 2000000 ohms.